# Tkinter GUI creates another frame with its own buttons and entries, how can I save this product to be loaded at anytime?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, saving-data

I created a tkinter GUI, that according to the data entered in it, creates another frame with its own buttons, entries and functions.

Now, I want the user to be able to save this product as a file, and be able to open it when ever it's needed, that has the same buttons and entries that were created.

I have tried `filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=...  )`   but it does not work. I have been looking for a filetype for tkinter files. But maybe, because I am new to python I am not seeing the correct path to finding an answer. I will really appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: *"I have been looking for a filetype for tkinter files."* There are no such things as *tkinter files*, tkinter is a library for Python. So *tkinter files* are .py or .pyw files (or any packaged executable). What are you actually trying to accomplish, what's the end goal?

Comment: The GUI creates another frame according to the info entered by the user. This new GUI has buttons that gets from certain files and buttons that can open the browser in specific web pages. The process were the user enters is long, so what I want, is to save this new window (GUI),  so the user doesn't have to go trough the process of creating the same GUI all over again.

Comment: So that every time the user loads the program it loads up with the information the user entered last time?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: You can't *save* the layout and content of tkinter widgets between program instances because you have to draw them in the first place. What you can do is output the information to a file which the program draws information from the next time it loads.

Comment: Thank you Ethan! Will that be a text file? and then draw the information from a list?

Comment: A `.txt` file could work but a `.json` is probably more suited.

Comment: Thank you Ethan for pointing me in the right direction. I have an idea of what .json is, but I will have to learn to create it and how to extract from it. I just did a search on youtube and I think I found some tutorials. Thanks again Ethan, you saved me many days looking for the wrong thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try playing around with the below. It does what I think you need it to:

```
from tkinter import *
import json

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.keys = ["0", "1", "2"]
        self.widget = [(Label(self.root), Entry(self.root)), (Label(self.root), Entry(self.root)), (Label(self.root), Entry(self.root))]
        self.button = Button(self.root, text="Save", command=self.save)
        for i in self.widget:
            [1].pack()
        for i in self.widget:
            i[0].pack()
       self.button.pack()
        try:
            with open("data.json", "r") as f:
                self.data = json.load(f)
                f.close()
                for i in self.keys:
                    self.widget[int(i)][0].configure(text=self.data[i])
            print(self.data)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File not found")
        except KeyError:
            print("Keys do not match")
    def save(self):
        for (i, c) in self.widget:
            i.configure(text=c.get())
        with open("data.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump({self.keys[0]: self.widget[0][1].get(), self.keys[1]: self.widget[1][1].get(), self.keys[2]: self.widget[2][1].get()}, f)
            f.close()

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```